# Using cypress fails on the first attempt but always passes on the second without retrying

Tags: testing, cypress

**Clarification**

I am making the test fail on purpose. I have enabled 1 retry on failed tests.

**The Problem**

If the test fails on `Attempt 1`, I expect it should also fail on `Attempt 2`.

**Actual behaviour**

The test fails on `Attempt 1` but then is marked as passed on `Attempt 2` without actually retrying.

**Some Details**

I have a number of Cypress's tests. In this particular test, I'm checking part of the `URL` to contain a specific string and making it fail on purpose. That fails on `timeout` on the first attempt but always passes on the second attempt without re-trying.

Why doesn't it retry or fail on a second attempt? I believe it's something to do with my assertion.

[image]

I have also tried with `expect` and `then` as they are run asynchronously

```js
         cy.url().then(url => {
            expect(url).to.include("homssse.faces")
        });
```

**Setup Details**

On my `command.js` file I have added a `login` command

```js
    Cypress.Commands.add('login', (username, password) => {
      cy.visit('signOn.faces')
        .get(".global-header__logo")
        .should("be.visible")

      cy
        .get('input[name="username"]')
        .type(Cypress.env('username'))
        .should('have.value', Cypress.env('username'));

      cy
        .get('input[name="password"]')
        .type(Cypress.env('password'))
        .should('have.value', Cypress.env('password'));

      cy
        .get('[name="submit"]')
        .click();
    })
```

In my `critical_user_journeys.spec.js` i have multiple tests, but I am showing here the first one. In this test, after I call `login` I want to assert I have landed on my Home page, but here I am failing the test on purpose to verify that it indeed fails when it actually breaks. I have enabled retries on all the tests coming from `cypress.json`, so naturally, when a test fails, it will attempt to run again. I have also set timeouts, details are further below.

```js
    describe("Critical User Journeys", function () {

        it("signs in user and lands on 'HomePage'", () => {
            cy
                .login()

            cy.location().should((loc) => {
                expect(loc.href).to.include(
                    'this_doesnt_exist_on_the_url' // break tests on purpose
                )
            })
        })
    })
```

Some of the setup on the `cypress.json` file

```js
    ...
      "pageLoadTimeout": 30000,
      "defaultCommandTimeout": 20000,
      "chromeWebSecurity": false,
      "retries": {
        "runMode": 1,
        "openMode": 1
      }
    ...
```

**Important Note**

When the assertion is changed to `expect(true).to.be.false;` both attempts fail, and that is the behaviour I expect to see with the other assertion, too.

Thanks

Comment: Does the url change before you do the check ? Add a wait before and check if it still does the same. Ive had a similar issue, I ended up adding a wait and it worked from there. Otherwise get the screen to reload before doing the check.

Comment: Double check your assertion. You are trying to assert `homssse.faces` but it looks like the url is home.faces...

Comment: I am failing the test on purpose. The problem is `Attempt 1` fails and that is as expected, but then `Attempt 2` does not actually attempt anything and passes the test. I am expecting that `Attempt 2` will fail too and the whole test will be marked as `Failed`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to have the expected behaviour by adding an empty `beforeEach` hook inside `describe`. I am not sure why adding this changes the behaviour, but when I saw it mentioned on the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries#How-It-Works), I added one to check the outcome and got the results I was looking for. Still not sure if this is by design or a bug, though.

This is how `critical_user_journeys.spec.js` file looks now

```js
        describe("Critical User Journeys", function () {

            beforeEach(function () {})

            it("signs in user and lands on 'HomePage'", () => {
                cy
                    .login()

                cy.location().should((loc) => {
                    expect(loc.href).to.include(
                        'this_doesnt_exist_on_the_url' // break tests on purpose
                    )
                })
            })
        })
```

With this implementation `Attempt 1` fails, then `Attempt 2` fails, too. As a result, the whole test is marked as 'Failed'.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways of adding the assertion. Do they all fail on the first try ?

```
cy.url().should('eq', 'http://localhost:8000/users/1/edit') // => true
```

or

```
cy.url().should('include', '/index.html')
```

Comment: Tried both assertions and both fail on attempt 1 but both pass on attempt 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a timeout to make sure the url is resolved. The default timeout is 4000 ms.

```js
cy.url({timeout: 10000}).should('include', 'home.faces')
```

Comment: I am failing the test on purpose. The problem is `Attempt 1` fails and that is as expected, but then` Attempt 2` does not actually attempt anything and passes the test. I am expecting that `Attempt `2 will fail too and the whole test will be marked as` Failed`. I'll update the question to make this clear, I think people are confused of the problem am facing.

Comment: Thats a good idea. Also please add the entire test as well, so that it gives more context to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Vergil C. Have you tried applying the test tries on the test level and rather than globally ?

Comment: yes I have tried. I get the same output, where `Attempt 1` fails, `Attempt 2` passes. However, when I change assertion to `expect(true).to.be.false;`, both attempts run and both fail.